# Display website images correctly on mobile phones without zoom complett

Tags: html, css

I have several images on my website and have encountered the issue that the images are either too heavily zoomed or excessively stretched on mobile devices.

To address this, I applied styles to display the images in their entirety. Unfortunately, this results in dark areas above and below the image, and sometimes on the left and right as well.

I could make the images transparent, but this would create many gaps.

As seen in my picture, I would like to eliminate the dark area, and making it transparent is not a suitable solution. The representation of the image on mobile devices should remain as it is now, but without the darkness at the top and bottom.

[PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHezX.png)

[PHONE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUPhk.png)

Code:

```
<style>
  html {
    zoom: 0.80;
  }
.columns .column.main {
  padding: 0;
}
.pt_row {clear: both;}
hr.solid, hr {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.06);
}
.ls-10em {
  letter-spacing: .01em;
}
.ls-25em {
  letter-spacing: .025em;
}
.ls-negative-25em {
    letter-spacing: -.025em;
}
.font-weight-semibold, .text-weight-semibold {
    font-weight: 600;
}
.pc-position-absolute {
  position: absolute!important;
}
.right-0, .pc-right-0 {
  right: 0;
}
.bottom-0, .pc-bottom-0 {
  bottom: 0;
}
.top-0, .pc-top-0 {
    top: 0;
}
.left-0, .pc-left-0 {
    top: 0;
}
.pt_btn3.btn {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: none; /* Ändern Sie "uppercase" zu "none" */
  padding: 1.2em 2.5em;
  letter-spacing: .01em;
}
.pt_btn3.btn-sm {
  padding: 1em 2.25em;
}
.porto-ultimate-content-box {
  position: relative;
  font-size: inherit;
}
.porto-ultimate-content-box .btn-container {
  font-size: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.porto-ultimate-content-box .price del {
    font-size: 65%;
    color: #a7a7a7;
}
.coupon-text-sale {
  transform: rotate(0);
  letter-spacing: .01em;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
.coupon-text-sale i {
  font-style: normal;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.5em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  font-size: .65em;
  opacity: .6;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}
.coupon-text-sale b {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ee8379;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin-right: .25rem;
}
</style>



<style>
  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .porto-ultimate-content-box.has-content-pos {
      background-size: contain !important;
      background-position: center !important;
    }
  }
</style>



<div class="pt_row porto-inner-container" style="margin-top: 20px; background-color: #fff !important;">
  <div class="porto-wrap-container container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="m-b-md pt_column_container col-md-8">
        <!-- Großes Bild -->
        <div class="wpb_wrapper pt_column-inner">
          <div class="porto-ultimate-content-box-container">
            <!-- Online-Deals Text über dem großen Bild einfügen -->
            <h3 style="font-size: 36px; line-height: 1; font-weight: 700; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 12px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 12px; color: #000 !important;" class="pt_custom_heading align-self-start align-left text-capitalize heading-light">
              Online-Deals
            </h3>

            <!-- Großes Bild -->
            <div class="porto-ultimate-content-box has-content-pos justify-content-center"
                 style="background-size: 100% 100%;
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        background-position: center center;
                        min-height: 285px;
                        background-image: url('{{media url=wysiwyg/Banner/rawento-sparfuchs-banner.png}}');
                        padding-right: 40px;
                        background-color: #181a1c;
                        margin-bottom: 20px;">
              <!-- Inhalt des großen Bildes -->
<!--
              <h3 style="font-size: 18px; line-height: 1; font-weight: 700; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 12px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 12px;" class="pt_custom_heading align-self-end background-color-primary align-right text-uppercase heading-light">
                50% RABATT
              </h3>
              <h2 style="font-size: 40px; line-height: 1; font-weight: 700;" class="pt_custom_heading mb-2 ls-10em align-right text-uppercase heading-light">
                PORTOGEAR 2
              </h2>
              <h3 style="font-size: 28px; line-height: 1.2; font-weight: 600;" class="pt_custom_heading price mb-0 align-right heading-light"><del>€59</del> €29</h3>
-->
              <div class="btn-container pc-position-absolute pc-bottom-0 pc-right-0 d-inline-block" style="margin-right: 20px;">
                <button class="pt_btn3 btn btn-lg btn-quaternary">Mehr erfahren</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Neue Bildzeile mit zwei Spalten (Teil 1 links, Teil 2 rechts) -->
        <div class="row">
          <!-- Teil 1 des neuen Bildes (links) -->
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper pt_column-inner">
              <div class="porto-ultimate-content-box-container m-b-md">
                <div class="porto-ultimate-content-box has-content-pos justify-content-end"
                     style="background-size: 100% 100%;
                            background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Änderung: Entfernt background-repeat */
                            background-position: left center;
                            min-height: 285px;
                            background-image: url('{{media url=wysiwyg/Banner/rawento-ostern-lego-banner.png}}');
                            padding-right: 10px;
                            padding-bottom: 20px;
                            background-color: #181a1c;">
                  <!-- Inhalt des Teils 1 des neuen Bildes -->
                  <div class="btn-container mb-0 text-right" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                    <button class="pt_btn3 pt_btn3-shape-default btn btn-sm btn-quaternary">
                      Jetzt entdecken
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Teil 2 des neuen Bildes (rechts) -->
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper pt_column-inner">
              <div class="porto-ultimate-content-box-container m-b-md">
                <div class="porto-ultimate-content-box has-content-pos justify-content-end"
                     style="background-size: 100% 100%;
                            background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Änderung: Entfernt background-repeat */
                            background-position: left center;
                            min-height: 285px;
                            background-image: url('{{media url=wysiwyg/smartwave/porto/homepage/29/your_new_image_part2.jpg}}');
                            padding-left: 10px;
                            padding-bottom: 20px;
                            background-color: #181a1c;">
                  <!-- Inhalt des Teils 2 des neuen Bildes -->
                  <div class="btn-container mb-0 text-right" style="margin-right: 20px;">
                    <button class="pt_btn3 pt_btn3-shape-default btn btn-sm btn-quaternary">
                      Jetzt entdecken
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>







      <!-- Grid mit hellgrauem Hintergrund -->
      <div class="pt_column_container col-md-4">
       <div class="wpb_wrapper pt_column-inner" style="background-color: #f2f2f2; padding: 20px;">
          <h3 style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1; font-weight: 700; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 12px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 12px; color: #000 !important;" class="pt_custom_heading align-self-start align-left text-capitalize heading-light">
            Entdecke auch unsere Angebote!
          </h3>

          <!-- Neues Bild über "Flash-Sales KONSOLEN" -->
          <div class="porto-ultimate-content-box-container m-b-md">
            <div class="porto-ultimate-content-box has-content-pos justify-content-end"
                 style="background-size: contain;
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        background-position: left center;
                        min-height: 75px; /* Geänderte Höhe */
                        background-image: url('{{media url=wysiwyg/smartwave/porto/homepage/29/your_image.jpg}}');
                        padding-right: 20px;
                        padding-bottom: 20px;
                        background-color: #181a1c;">
              <!-- Inhalt des neuen Bildes -->
              <div class="btn-container mb-0 text-right">
                <button class="pt_btn3 pt_btn3-shape-default btn btn-sm btn-quaternary">
                  Jetzt entdecken
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Erstes kleine Bild -->
          <div class="wpb_wrapper pt_column-inner">
            <div class="porto-ultimate-content-box-container m-b-md">
              <div class="porto-ultimate-content-box has-content-pos justify-content-end"
                   style="background-size: 100% 100%;
                          background-repeat: no-repeat;
                          background-position: left center;
                          min-height: 190px;
                          background-image: url('{{media url=wysiwyg/smartwave/porto/homepage/29/your_new_image_part2}}');
                          padding-right: 20px;
                          padding-bottom: 20px;
                          background-color: #181a1c;">
                <!-- Inhalt des ersten kleinen Bildes -->
                <h3 style="font-size: 13px; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); line-height: 1; font-weight: 700;" class="pt_custom_heading mb-2 ls-25em align-right text-uppercase">
                  Flash-Sales
                </h3>
                <h2 style="font-size: 28px; line-height: 0.9; font-weight: 700;" class="pt_custom_heading ls-10em mb-5 align-right heading-light">
                  KONSOLEN
                </h2>
                <div class="btn-container mb-0 text-right">
                  <button class="pt_btn3 pt_btn3-shape-default btn btn-sm btn-quaternary">
                    Jetzt entdecken
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Zweites kleine Bild, in zwei Teile aufgeteilt -->
          <div class="wpb_wrapper pt_column-inner">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="porto-ultimate-content-box-container m-b-md">
                  <div class="porto-ultimate-content-box"
                       style="background-size: 100% 100%;
                              background-repeat: no-repeat;
                              background-position: center center;
                              min-height: 284px; /* Halbe Höhe des ursprünglichen Bildes */
                              background-image: url('{{media url=wysiwyg/smartwave/porto/homepage/29/shop29_home_banner3.jpg}}');
                              padding-top: 10px; /* Halbe Padding-Top des ursprünglichen Bildes */
                              padding-left: 25px;
                              background-color: #181a1c;">
                    <!-- Inhalt des zweiten kleinen Bildes, erster Teil -->
                    <h3 style="font-size: 13px; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); line-height: 1; font-weight: 700;" class="pt_custom_heading mb-1 ls-25em align-left text-uppercase">
                      CHECK NEUE KABELLOSE
                    </h3>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 23px; line-height: 1; font-weight: 700;" class="pt_custom_heading ls-10em mb-3 align-left heading-light">
                      CONTROLLER
                    </h2>
                    <h3 style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1; font-weight: 700;" class="pt_custom_heading coupon-text-sale mb-0 align-left text-uppercase heading-light"><i>Bis zu</i><b>50%</b> RABATT</h3>
                    <div class="btn-container pc-position-absolute pc-bottom-0 pc-right-0 text-right" style="margin-right: 0px;">
                      <button class="pt_btn3 btn btn-sm btn-quaternary">Jetzt entdecken</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="porto-ultimate-content-box-container m-b-md">
                  <div class="porto-ultimate-content-box"
                       style="background-size: 100% 100%;
                              background-repeat: no-repeat;
                              background-position: center center;
                              min-height: 284px; /* Halbe Höhe des ursprünglichen Bildes */
                              background-image: url('{{media url=wysiwyg/smartwave/porto/homepage/29/shop29_home_banner3.jpg}}');
                              padding-top: 10px; /* Halbe Padding-Top des ursprünglichen Bildes */
                              padding-left: 25px;
                              background-color: #181a1c;">
                    <!-- Inhalt des zweiten kleinen Bildes, erster Teil -->
                    <h3 style="font-size: 13px; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); line-height: 1; font-weight: 700;" class="pt_custom_heading mb-1 ls-25em align-left text-uppercase">
                      CHECK NEUE KABELLOSE
                    </h3>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 23px; line-height: 1; font-weight: 700;" class="pt_custom_heading ls-10em mb-3 align-left heading-light">
                      CONTROLLER
                    </h2>
                    <h3 style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1; font-weight: 700;" class="pt_custom_heading coupon-text-sale mb-0 align-left text-uppercase heading-light"><i>Bis zu</i><b>50%</b> RABATT</h3>
                    <div class="btn-container pc-position-absolute pc-bottom-0 pc-right-0 text-right" style="margin-right: 0px;">
                      <button class="pt_btn3 btn btn-sm btn-quaternary">Jetzt entdecken</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you change the height of the image container element in mobile mode? and i think you better use tags like section, aside etc to make your code more readable rather than just nested div tags

Comment: These images from your screenshot clearly give the impression, that the are more on the "content" than the "decoration" side of things - so they should rather not have been put in there as _background_ images to begin with, but as _real_ images. [...]

Comment: [...] And once you do that, your problem is likely to go away as well - because then the images can be rendered according to their intrinsic aspect ratio, instead of being rendered as the cover-ing background image of a div with _fixed_ dimensions (which will of course leave space beside the image in either the horizontal or vertical direction, when the aspect ratios _don't_ match.)

Comment: Remove or decrease the `min-height: 284px;` inline-styles in the `porto-ultimate-content-box-container` divs – those are responsible for the unnecessary height.